# Microsoft Dynamics 2011 and SBS2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-sbs-2008, microsoft-dynamics-crm

Got a question for anyone with Microsoft CRM 2011 experience.

According to [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg554691.aspx) page I can run Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 on a Small Business Server 2008 Standard as long as I install SQL Server 2008 R2.

Well, i've installed SQL Server 2008 R2 but when I go to install the CRM it says my operating system is not supported and it just gives me a link to the above.
According to requirements I need
SBS2008 R2 got it and its at SP1
SQL Server 2008 R2
IIS 7 or above

All of this software is part of the Microsoft Action Pack if that makes a difference which I can't imagine is the case.

Thoughts from anyone with CRM 2011 experience would be greatly appriciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your server have SP2 for Server 2008? Later SBS 2008 installs had it slipstreamed in, but if not this is a requirement for CRM 2011.

Comment: The page doesn't say it needs SBS2008 SP2 but I it notes Server 2008 SP2 so I am doing that now. I had it up to SP1 and 95% of all other updates. Anyway, I am running to the updates now. We'lll see what happens. I'll let you know. Thanks!!

Comment: I'll take your word for it. I attempted to install SP2 and it blew my server to kingdom come. After trying to repair it for the last 8 hours I gave up and am installing SBS 2011. Then I'll try the CRM again. Thanks for the help

Comment: Just FYI - Installed SBS2011 and Microsfot CRM and it works great.